# how to remove # from url in angularjs 1.6.4

Tags: html, angularjs

I have tried all the methods available on a stack and given on angularjs official documentation, so please don't mark it as a duplicate. I'm creating an E-commerce site so is it good that I use angular 4 or 5 in it. Please help me.
The code I've tried is given.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : mainController
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <base href="/">
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check browser support for the html5 history API:

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```